# Firebase made local datastore inaccessable when added to a Golang app

Tags: google-app-engine, go, firebase

I want to use Firebase Auth UI with a Google AppEngine app written in Go.  I installed Firebase and used the Firebase console to add my app.     It appears that Firebase took control of the local dev.  datastore file (something keeps making the directory it's in *read only* so Python can't open it when I issue a new data_path instruction).

If I delete the Firebase app, a warning message indicates: "You lose access to your entire project, including your project's apps"
Does this mean that the resources of my original GAE Go app will be deleted too?

For now I just want to restore my Golang datastore connectivity in my development environment - is it safe to delete this Firebase project?  Should I remove the Firebase tools ? 
thanks!